# Parameterized v-for directive

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, vue-directives

I'm using `v-for` to produce a set of vuetify `v-timeline-item` with elements being customized based on values stored in a customization object:

```
<v-timeline-item
   v-for="target in targetsList"
     :key="target.uid"
     :color="typesConfig[target.format].color"
     :icon="target.icon"
     large
     fill-dot
>
```

I would like to pick a color from the `typesConfig` object based on the value of `target.format`.

`typesConfig` is a computed property that looks like this:

```
const typesConfig = {
    doc: {
       color: 'red lighten-2',
       icon: 'mdi-star',
    }, etc...
```

I'm having trouble figuring out how to grab the color value from the object and assign it to `:color`. I have tried all sorts of things including string literals with no luck :(

I hope the above is clear and your help would be appreciated.

thank you.

Comment: could provide a codepen sample or the structure of the relevant parts from your code

Comment: say `target.format="doc"` I'd like to retrieve the color value from the `typesConfig` object using "doc" as the key so that the `:color` property (in the `v-for` loop) ends up being `:color="red lighten-2"`

Comment: How does your target list looks like?

Comment: `targetsList: [
            {
                uid: 'ABC',
                subject: 'S1',
                format: 'doc',
                notes: "some notes",
                date: 'Feb 10, 2020',
                color: 'red lighten-2',
                icon: 'mdi-star'
            }, ` etc....  the idea is to remove the color and icons properties from each item in the targetsList array into the above-mentioned `typesConfig` object.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your code. Maybe try using vue-devtools to trace the properties passed to `v-timeline-item`

Comment: I'm sorry for taking so long to respond to your feedback guys. when I posted the question, i was focused on whether this line was being evaluated properly `:color="typesConfig[target.format].color" and I thought it wasn't. the problem was elsewhere in the data contained in `tpyesConfig computed property. So the code was fine like @StephenThomas said and made me rethink the code elsewhere. thanks a lot for jumping to help.

Answer (score 0):

You said ***typesConfig is a computed property that looks like this: ...*** but that's not what a computed property looks like.

It looks like you have defined a constant outside of the Vue object.

I mocked up your component with `typesConfig` as a data property and the template you have works perfectly.

You would only need a computed property if you were computing from something else, say `targetsList`, but you intend to remove color and icon from those objects.

So, it's likely you just need a data property that is initialized from your const, something like

```js
const typesConfig = {
  doc: {
    color: 'red lighten-2',
    icon: 'mdi-star',
  },
}

export default {
  data: () => ({
    targetsList: [ 
      { uid: 'ABC', subject: 'S1', format: 'doc', notes: "some notes", date: 'Feb 10, 2020' },
      { uid: 'def', subject: 'S1', format: 'doc', notes: "some notes", date: 'Feb 10, 2020' },
      { uid: 'ghi', subject: 'S1', format: 'doc', notes: "some notes", date: 'Feb 10, 2020' }
    ],
    typesConfig: typesConfig
  })
};
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to mock this up to help. your reverse engineering is close to the real code however `typesConfig` is a computed property that, like you have in the code transforms the data of another object and its' in that transformation the bug was lurking! Cheers for the hlep.